# Retrofit expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm working on interacting with my REST API from android via retrofit and RXAndroid, and I've run into a problem.

When I send a GET request to my 'api/users/{id}/{id}/classes', my api responds with a list of the users classes, like so:

```
{
   "classes": [
    {
         "assignments": [
         {
             "asstype": 0, 
             "classs_id": 1, 
             "desc": "Read", 
             "due": "9/14/16", 
             "id": 1
         }
         ], 
   "badge": 0, 
   "days": "W", 
   "id": 1, 
   "location": "W.Claire Harris Textiles 136A", 
   "name": "STS 1101", 
   "professor": "Stickel", 
   "time": "5:00 - 6:15", 
   "user_id": 1
 }, 
 {
  "assignments": [], 
  "badge": 1, 
  "days": "TR", 
  "id": 2, 
  "location": "Atrium 201L", 
  "name": "HIST 2111", 
  "professor": "Pierce", 
  "time": "6:30 - 7:45", 
  "user_id": 1
  }
 ]
}
```

My interface looks like this:

```
@GET("api/users/{user_id}/classes")
Ovservable<List<Clazz>> getClasses(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Path("user_id")int user_id);
```

I call it from my fragment like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_classes, container, false);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(Sched.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RecyclerView classesRV = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.classRec);
    ClassInterface classAPI = retrofit.create(ClassInterface.class);
    Observable<List<Class>> classes = classAPI.getClasses("Basic " +Base64.encodeToString("joyod3@gmail.com:nightman_420".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP), 1);

    classes.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Class>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Class> classes) {
                    classesRV.setAdapter(new ClassRecyclerViewAdapter(classes, getContext()));
                    classesRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                }
            });
    return rootView;
}
```

My Class object looks like this along with getters and setters:

```
public class Class {
private int id;
private String name;
private int badge;
private String professor;
private String location;
private String days;
private String time;
private int user_id;
private List<Assignment> assignments;

public Class() {
}
```

Shouldn't gson see the "classes": [] array and parse the objects from it? What have I done wrong

Comment: Well, your JSON is an object, not an array. It contains an array of classes, but the result of the REST call is not the array itself. The only reason why Gson would look inside of it for an array of classes is if it is trying to map your JSON to some object that contains `List<Clazz>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare has mentioned, with this JSON response structure you would need some intermediate class to hold the collection of `Clazz`s (or write a custom deserializer altogether). Like this:

```
public class ClassHolder {

    List<Clazz> classes;

}
```

The return type of `getClasses()` would change to `Observable<ClassHolder>` accordingly.

Comment: I figured the solution would be something like this. Thanks!